# SpriteMaterial without sizeAttenuation in Three.js

Tags: three.js, sprite, texture2d

i need a (nameplate) sprite without sizeAttenuation in Three.js and it should looks like this example:

[image]

```
//load image with 256x128px 32bit png

var spriteMap = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("tex/plates/mytest.png");
var spriteMat = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({map:spriteMap, transparent:true, sizeAttenuation:false});
var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(spriteMat);
...
spriteMat.map.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
```

The result is not blurry, but its not correctly and hav some artefacts what i dont want:

[image]

Here is my second try with (**THREE.LinearFilter**), also not what i want cos its too blurry:

[image]

Renderer size: 1200x800px (not full window)

So, i dont know if its a problem with the filter, position or scaling. The first example seems like a bitmap text, but i really dont know how i can solve this problem. I also dont need a 2d sprite in screenspace. I need the nameplate in 3d worldspace behind other objects. I have really no idea how i can solve this, pls anyone can help me with this problem?

Comment: You say you "need a sprite with sizeAttenuation" and yet in your code you have `sizeAttenuation:false`.  You also say you have a problem with artifacts. So what is the actual question? Hazarding a guess and judging by the comments in the code you posted `load image with 256x128px 32bit png`, I suspect your problems lie with the small image you are loading.

Comment: Oh my fail xD yes i mean without this. sizeAttenuation:false is correct. u mean the loaded image is to small? i dont tried a bigger resolution, cos i thought its big enough, its only a small nameplate. the text in the images should have the same size as u can see it here, not bigger. so i use images for the text to display a name or whatever..

Comment: so the images what i posted are only screens. i need only the text what u can see. omg i got this problem in ue4 too. i was reading much about text sprites, but that dont help me, cause i want these old bitmap quality, but without artifacts or blurry. i was wondering if this is so hard to realize :o

Comment: Well i found this technique to render the text into a canvas: https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/a2ogz9vx/ its very nice, but the text is a little bit flickering if the text is a bit smaller is that only a filter problem?

Comment: Anyone can help? or maybe multiple renderer can solve this problem to keep the bitmap text always same size with sharpen edges?

Comment: Have you tried larger images like I suggested?

Comment: Yes i tried, but no luck, the same result. I think, there is no way to manage that.